# How can you tell which sites are HTML & JS and which sites are rendered through JS using React, Angular etc.?

Tags: javascript, scrapy, rabbitmq, scrapy-splash

When creating my first crawler, I wanted to check whether a website is rendered using some framework or not. I know that I can use SplashRequest in order to render it using a headless browser, but that is not efficient. How can I figure out which sites need to be put through Splash and which sites do not without actually making useless SplashRequests?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can simple disable JS using this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en, on the website you want to scrape and see if data you want to scrape is available on the page or not, if not, you will either need to inspect AJAX calls of the website, or use any headless browser like Selenium or Splash

I recommend not to use SplashRequest, its very poorly programmed, and less transparent to the developer, I will suggest use Scrapy Selenium

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
That does not seem very efficient, as I still have to create some requests for every page before determining whether it is JS rendered or not. It is more efficient to render everything using a headless browser than using your method.